# Dynamic Input Fields don't POST with Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, dynamic-forms

I currently have a Javascript function that clones part of my form (select box) as many times as needed, giving the end user the option of adding as many fields as required. Everything is working fine except that only the hard-coded HTML is sent via POST with my form, the rest are not included. Why is this and how can it be fixed?

Javascript:

```
$(function()
{
    var template = $('#inventoryItems .inventory:first').clone(),
        inventoryCount = 0;

    var addInventory = function()
    {
        inventoryCount++;
        var inventory = template.clone().find(':input').each(function()
        {
            var newLabel = "invItem{" + inventoryCount + "]";
            $(this).prev().attr('id', newLabel);
            $(this).prev().attr('name', newLabel);
        }).end()
        .attr('id', 'inv' + inventoryCount)
        .appendTo('#inventoryItems > fieldset');
    };

    $('.btnAddInventory').click(addInventory);
});
```

HTML

```
                        <fieldset style="width:62%; float:left; margin-left: 19%;">

                            <div id="inv1" class="inventory" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                                <select name="invItem[0]" id="invItem[0]" style="width:92%;">

                                    <?php
                                        getInventoryOptions($dp_conn, "", $datacenter);
                                    ?>
                                </select>

                                <input class="btnRemoveInventory" type="button" style="background: url(images/icn_trash.png) no-repeat; cursor:pointer; border: none;">
                            </div>

                        </fieldset><div class="clear"></div>

                        <!-- Add Inventory Button -->
                        <div style="width:62%; margin:0; padding:0; float: right; margin-right: 19%">
                            <input class="btnAddInventory" type="button" value="Add Item" style="float: right;">
                        </div><div class="clear"></div>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this:

```
var newLabel = "invItem{" + inventoryCount + "]";
//---------------------^
```

should be

```
var newLabel = "invItem[" + inventoryCount + "]";
```

Comment: Thank you! Winter answered a bit quicker so I will accept his but appreciate your response :)

Comment: @BrettPowell Actually to be fair, Dr.Molle's answer was in 18 seconds before mine.

Comment: I must have misread the times when I checked. Thank you though, I will go ahead and accept this one then.

Answer (score 1):

When you are updating your id and name for your inputs you are replacing it with `invItem{x]` instead of `invItem[x]`.

Comment: Wow, so simple and yet caused so many problems. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @BrettPowell The simpler it is, the harder it is to find sometimes, without extra eyes looking at it. I often find myself staring at code wondering why it doesn't work, just to realize I'm using otherwise perfectly valid PHP syntax/functions, but in Javascript.